# Determining elements in the Render Tree

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, browser

In the context of a web browser, the [Render Tree](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/render-tree-construction) only has elements that will be visible on the webpage. So elements with `display: none` won't make it to the render tree. But I understand that elements like those with `height: 0` and `position : absolute; left: 100%` are included in the render tree, even though they won't be visible on the webpage when rendered. So why are such elements still included in the render tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Because they may still hold visible child nodes:

```css
.no-height {
  height: 0;
};
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="no-height">
  <p class="absolute">still here</p>
</div>
```

- Because they still can have borders or margins which could be visible

```css
.no-height {
  height: 0;
  border: 5px solid;
  margin: 120px;
};
```

```html
<div class="no-height">
</div>
I should be at top
```

- Because they could  have some influence on other visible nodes:

```css
.no-height {
  height: 0;
};
```

```html
<div>
  some inline<div class="no-height"></div>text
</div>
```

- ...